# How can I transfer my bash history to a new system?

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, bash-history

My `bash` history is my memory, it contains commands that I don't want to loose when I update to a newer version of Ubuntu or change my computer.

Is it possible to transfer the commands database to a fresh installation?

Comment: If it's that important, I hope you backup regularly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your bash history is saved in a plain text file, called by default `.bash_history`.

Unless you modified the `$HISTFILE` variable you should find it in your home directory:

```
$ echo $HISTFILE
/home/sylvain/.bash_history
```

If you keep your home partition when updating or reinstalling your system and if `$HISTFILE` is saved on this partition, there's nothing else to do.

To transfer the file to a new computer, just save it on a USB drive and replace the existing `.bash_history` of the target system.

If `HISTTIMEFORMAT` was set on the "old" system, don't forget to set it again otherwise the timestamps of the new commands won't be saved as comments in the "new" `.bash_history` file.

In case you would like to merge both old and new with new being saved at the end of the history file, you can use this [method](https://superuser.com/a/586068):

```
sudo apt-get install moreutils
cat .bash_history.old $HISTFILE | sponge $HISTFILE
```

Comment: Why 2 calls to cat? cat can read multiple files: `cat .bash_history.old $HISTFILE | sponge $HISTFILE`

Comment: @glennjackman Absolutely, fixed.